# deadlatch operates by a simple push instead of push & turn

Tags: lock

The door locks at my church are constantly being accidentally locked because the deadlatch button can latch by a simple push. Someone comes up and turns the handle, but inadvertently pushes the button - now it's locked. It can be unlocked from the inside by operating the handle, but requires someone to be inside.

The locks can be more securely locked by pushing the button in and turning it 90 degrees. It requires someone to unturn it 90 degrees.

Is there a way to disable the "push only" locking mechanism?

Comment: I'm not sure the brand. They look similar to this. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Schlage-Elan-Satin-Chrome-Light-Commercial-Keyed-Entry-Door-handle-F51CS-V-ELA-626/203074077

Comment: Got it. Yes, you're probably going to want to replace those with more appropriate hardware.

Comment: Please post a photo

Answer (score 1):

Replacing with more suitable locks (or non-locking set where appropriate) is likely the effective solution. Particularly for a quasi-public or commercial use such as a church.

I have disabled the internal lock button entirely by removing parts, so the door could only be locked/unlocked with a key, but I can't see removing the push function and retaining the turn function (since the turn function works by keeping the button pushed in.)

But one with only a turn function can be purchased. Providing only a turn function will *not* solve the problem if you have a prankster rather than accidental engagement. However, I think I *have* experienced doors where they would not close without turning the knob if they were locked (without the latch being a deadbolt.) But a clever prankster can defeat that...

Comment: When modifying such hardware you need to be _extremely_ careful to not create a fire escape hazard. All automatic unlock and intuitive egress functionality must remain.

Comment: Exiting the locked door from inside was tested. The only one I have experience with that would be a problem on is a non-push one that requires the button to be turned when exiting if locked. Disabling that button would be inappropriate. However, for a building use like a church, purchasing the correct type is certainly preferable.